# Store password on device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've got a button, where you can create a new password by entering and reentering it. 
When both are the same the password should be stored somewhere on the phone for further use.

For the moment i can ignore password safety.

How is the simplest way to store and read the password on the device?

```
btnLogin.TouchUpInside += delegate {
    if(password.Exists /*My Isolated storage or password file*/){
        ReturnToView();
} else{
    new UIAlertView("Password doesn't exists", "Create a new password, to log in", null, "Ok").Show();
}

};
```

I've tried something like this, but I don't know how to check if the password exists in the `.TXT`file.

```
void CreateUser(){    
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Password.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fileStorage));

    btnCreateUser.TouchUpInside += delegate {
       if(txtPassword.Text == txtRepeat.Text && txtPassword.Text.Length == 4){
           GoBackToView(); //Login
           Writer.WriteLine(txtPassword.Text);
           Writer.Close();
      } //here comes my else function, but that's not important.
    };
}
```

After this, a password should be created in a `.TXT`.
In a new method called `Login()` I'll do this.

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamReader Reader = null;
try 
    {
    Reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Password.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
    Reader.Close();
    }
catch
    {
    MessageBox.Show("File it not created");
    }
```

Somewhere in my login method, I want to check if the password is created when I've entered a password, and when I press my login button.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults and if your application is using CoreData you can use that as well.

Comment: Can you make a code sample?

Comment: No offense but Stack Overflow is not for asking any code. Please try on your own first. If you stuck somewhere we can help. If I am not wrong you want to make a login system for an application right?

Comment: That is correct, but I will try to see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer @manujmv posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243058/368379) can be translated to:

```
void StoreLoginCredentials(string password)
{
    var userDetails = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    userDetails.SetString(password, "password");
    userDetails.Synchronize();
}

bool CheckUserSession()
{
    var userDetails = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    return userDetails["password"] != null;
}

bool DestroyLoginCredentials()
{
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    defaults.RemovePersistentDomain(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier);
    return defaults.Synchronize();
}

string PasswordOfUser()
{
    var userDetails = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    return userDetails["password"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the password in NSUserDefaults. Just create the below method and pass the password to this method.

```
-(void)storeLoginCredentials:(NSString*)password    {

    userDetails = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDetails setObject:password forKey:@"password"];

    [userDetails synchronize];

}
```

Then if you want to check whether the user is logged in or not you can use the below method:

```
-(BOOL)checkUserSession {

    if ([userDetails objectForKey:@"password"]!= nil ) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

If you want to logged out the user, use below method.

```
-(void)destroyLoginCredentials  {

    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
}
```

You can take the password as

```
-(NSString *)passwordOfUser {

    return  [userDetails objectForKey:@"password"];
}
```

Comment: Can you do it in native? I'm not using Xcode, sorry for the inconvenience.